# pthreads: a thread that triggers other threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

Hello,
I'm new to multi-thread programming.
I'm trying to create a code that creates a thread THREAD1, that, after it has done something, it triggers two other threads, say THREAD2 and THREAD3, and then exits.

I wrote two possible solutions.

1) Use of condition variables (DOESN'T WORK: in some case I get a deadlock):

```c
pthread_mutex_t ready_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  ready_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
bool ready = false;

void* trigger(void*);
void* func1(void*);
void* func2(void*);

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;  
    pthread_create(&thread1, 0, &trigger, 0);
    pthread_create(&thread2, 0, &func1, 0);
    pthread_create(&thread3, 0, &func2, 0);
    pthread_join(thread1, 0);
    pthread_join(thread2, 0);
    pthread_join(thread3, 0);
}

void *trigger(void*)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ready_mutex);
    ready = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&ready_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ready_mutex);
    return 0;
}

void *func1(void*)
{
    while (!ready) // Needed to avoid spuriuos wake-up
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&ready_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&ready_cond, &ready_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ready_mutex);
    }
    std::cout << "In 'func1'>> Do something" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void *func2(void*)
{
    while (!ready) // Needed to avoid spuriuos wake-up
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&ready_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&ready_cond, &ready_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&ready_mutex);
    }
    std::cout << "In 'func2'>> Do something" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

2) THREAD1 directly creates the two other threads.

```c
pthread_mutex_t ready_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  ready_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
pthread_t thread3;

void* trigger(void*);
void* func1(void*);
void* func2(void*);

int main()
{
    pthread_create(&thread1, 0, &trigger, 0);

    pthread_join(thread1, 0);
    pthread_join(thread2, 0);
    pthread_join(thread3, 0);
}

void *trigger(void*)
{
    std::cout << "In 'trigger'>> Do something" << std::endl;

    pthread_create(&thread2, 0, &func1, 0);
    pthread_create(&thread3, 0, &func2, 0);

    return 0;
}

void *func1(void*)
{
    std::cout << "In 'func1'>> Do something" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void *func2(void*)
{
    std::cout << "In 'func2'>> Do something" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know your opinion.
Thank you very much

Comment: Your second implementation seems to work fine, what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Your second option is cleaner and nicer. I'd do that.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy: I just wonder if there is a better way to reach this goal. From POSIX manual pages, it seems to me that condition variables are better suited to this aim since they can be used to signal for a particular event.

Comment: Your "spurious wake-up" loop is not quite right:  you want to `lock`, then `while (!read) cond_wait()`, and then `unlock`.  As it is you check the value of a mutex-protected variable (`ready`) without first locking the mutex — not good.

Comment: @pilcrow: Yes, I know. Maxim Yegorushkin already pointed it out (see first answer below). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> Use of condition variables (DOESN'T WORK: in some case I get a deadlock):

The code doesn't lock the mutex when checking the state of shared variable `ready`. When it does lock the mutex `ready` may have well changed by that time, this is why you see deadlocks.

The correct version to wait for state change with a condition variable is (error checking omitted):

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&ready_mutex);
while(!ready) // Needed to avoid spuriuos wake-up
    pthread_cond_wait(&ready_cond, &ready_mutex);
// ready == true here
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ready_mutex);
```

The above assumes that `ready` is ever changed only when the same mutex is held.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, returning to my question, should I use condition variables (solution #1) or deferred thread creation (solution #2)?

Comment: @seg.fault I'd use [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor): given multiple solutions for a problem choose simpler one.